# How can I add an object to a form?

Tags: forms

How can I add an object to a form array to make it available to `hook_form_alter()` implementations?

I have an object I pass to a form, which may have the `new` property. I would like to implement `hook_form_alter()` in another module to add/change form items based on that property.

There is no need for the item to be available after submission. I would like to avoid the overhead of using a *value* form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add the entire object to the `$form` array: You can just add the property you need to share with the `hook_form_alter()` implementations, for example with the following code.

```php
$form['#mymodule_new'] = $object->new;
```

You don't have to worry about adding overhead because the values submitted in a form are transient by design, if they are not stored in the database.

As additional note, `$form['#mymodule_new']` is available to form validation and submission handlers. The array key should not be already used by other Drupal modules, including Drupal core modules, to avoid conflicts.